# Android AudioTrack Periodic Sounds

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio, arduino

Ok so I am attempting to do something that was definitely not intended to be used in the way I am trying to use it. Just want to put that disclaimer out there, but if anyone could help or has any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

I am attempting to output data over the headphone left and right audio jack by way of outputting square waves and using serial data transfer. My goal is actually to communicate between the android and my Arduino development board.

In fact I had a setup that was working and I was using AudioTrack in streaming mode to output a continually alternating pattern of HIGH and LOW (1V and 0V respectively). I was monitoring the output on a oscilloscope and it actually was not too bad. There was some awful ringing effects when I would go from LOW to HIGH,  but I fixed that with a small op amp circuit.

My current dilemma is however entirely Android software based. Basically I need AudioTrack to run on another thread, because it will be running continually as long as the app is open and so it can't cause the UI to freeze. I experimented with using AsyncTask and Handler. I have done some reading on IntentService and Threads.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it better to use AudioTrack in streaming mode or static mode given that I need to output data that will be continually changing based off of what the user has done in the UI (for example if the user moves a slider up or down the audio output pattern will need to change)
2. If I run AudioTrack in streaming: how to I not only get info from UI but also push data back to UI
3. If I run AudioTrack in static mode: how to I not only get info from UI but also push data back to UI and how do I assure the audiotrack is started at a regular interval, like once a millisecond or something of that nature
4. What helper class if any (or should I just use Threads) is best to make sure I can run Audio Track either continually or periodically without freezing UI.

Comment: A BlueTooth module (HC-06) only costs about 5 bucks... worth to try, isn't it?

Comment: That would work, but physical connection would be cheaper as I already have headphones with cut wires etc. And the nature of my project is such that I just want it to be a physical conection because once I get the data to the Arduino the data is going to be sent over RF to wireless receiver module anyway. So having two wireless connections just seems kind of a waste, when the arduino is guaranteed to be right next to my phone in testing and use.